# Proof of associativity of polynomials product (infinite variables)

Tags: polynomials, products, associativity

The product of polynomials in $R[X_i]_{i\in I}$ where $I$ is not necessarily finite is associative ($R$ commutative ring), but I can't find any detailed proof of this fact. Either it is left in exercice, either it is "obvious".

The question is quite the same (I guess...) as what Bourbaki assets to be obvious in Algebra A.III.27 §10 associativiy of bilinear product in total algebra...

So, either it is really obvious, but I lack some words of explanation ;), either some manipulations of sums and indices are required to be sure that it is obvious...

Anyone can give me details, or reference to a book or notes where it is well done, please ?

To be more precise, I want to prove that the product in $A^{(\mathbb{N}^{(I)})}$, that is $((a_\alpha)_{\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}}, (b_\beta)_{\beta\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}})\mapsto \left( \sum_{\alpha + \beta = \gamma} a_\alpha b_\beta\right)_{\gamma\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ is associative, and directly, not by any isomorphism for instance.

Comment: It is isomorphic to a (sub)ring of endomorphisms of its additive group, where the product is function composition hence associative.

Comment: Yes, but it is not exactly my question. I don't want a proof that is true, I want the "direct" proof. I'm goint to be more explicit ;).

Comment: It is analogous to a direct proof of associativity of matrix multiplication vs. a proof using associativity of function composition. Yes, of course one can give such direct proofs, but they are nothing but tedious calculations which lend no insight. So why insist on such a proof?

Comment: It's a point of view, no ? If the question arised, I consider it to be of importance... A good answer is for instance to be able to give self-contained material for the exposition of a non-trivial result to students who can't follow too long developpments on free algebra... And for someone who is weak in sums and indices manipulations, this is not a waste of time (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my "solution". Correct and comment ;) !

Let $a=(a_\alpha)_{\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$, $b=(b_\beta)_{\beta\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ and $c=(c_\gamma)_{\gamma\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ three elements of $R^{(\mathbb{N}^{(I)})}$, we prove the equality $a(bc)=(ab)c$ by showing that each member is equal to the polynomial $d=(d_\delta)_{\delta\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ where for all $\delta\in \text{Supp}(d)$, $d_\delta=\sum\limits_{\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\delta} a_\alpha b_\beta c_\gamma$.

When calculating with the formula giving the product, it comes easily that $(ab)c = (e_\epsilon)_{\epsilon\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ with $e_\epsilon = \sum\limits_{\rho+\gamma=\epsilon}\left(\sum\limits_{\alpha+\beta=\rho}a_\alpha b_\beta\right) c_\gamma$ for all $\epsilon\in\text{Supp}((ab)c)$, and $a(bc) = (f_\eta)_{\eta\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ with $f_\eta = \sum\limits_{\alpha+\tau=\eta}a_\alpha\left(\sum\limits_{\beta+\gamma=\tau}b_\beta c_\gamma\right) $ for all $\eta\in\text{Supp}(a(bc))$. What matters here is to see clearly which elements the sum is taken over.

In each case, it is the internal sums that lead the whole. Let $A=\text{Supp}(a)$, $B=\text{Supp}(b)$ and $C=\text{Supp}(c)$. Let's begin with counting the number of different elements $\rho$ of $\mathbb{N}^{(I)}$ which can be writtent as a sum $\alpha+\beta$ where $(\alpha,\beta)\in A\times B$ (this number $m$ ranges between $1$ and $\text{Card}(A)\times \text{Card}(B)$ !). Then, for each of these $\rho$, whose number is finite, the sum $\gamma+\rho$ equals to an $\epsilon$, and these are those $\epsilon$ which are the support of the product (there are exactly $m\times \text{Card}(C)$ of them).

Let's consider now, for $\delta$ in $\mathbb{N}^{(I)}$, the set $E_\delta=\{(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\in A\times B\times C \,/\, \alpha+\beta+\gamma =\delta\}$. As "$E_\delta\neq \emptyset$ if and only if $\delta\in \text{Supp}(d)$", we have for almost all of the $\delta$, $E_\delta=\emptyset$. Let $\delta$ be such that $E_\delta \neq \emptyset$. The idea is to write $E_\delta$ as a partition with the form of a product so as to be able to show both sums of $(ab)c$ (the same way is used for $a(bc)$).

Let $E'=\{\gamma\in C \,/\, \exists \lambda\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}, \gamma + \lambda = \delta\}$, and for $\gamma\in E'$, $E'_\gamma= \{(\alpha,\beta)\in A\times B \,/\, (\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\in E_\delta\}$. If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are two distinct elements of $E'$, then $E'_{\gamma_1}\cap E'_{\gamma_2}=\emptyset$. Indeed, if $(\alpha,\beta)\in E'_{\gamma_1}$, then $\alpha+\beta+\gamma_1= \delta$, so $\alpha+\beta=\delta-\gamma_1\neq \delta-\gamma_2$, and hence $\alpha+\beta +\gamma_2\neq \delta$, which implies $(\alpha,\beta)\notin E'_{\gamma_2}$. Moreover, if $\gamma\in E'$, there exists (an unique) $\lambda\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}$ such that $\gamma+\lambda = \delta$, and then for all $(\alpha,\beta) \in E'_\gamma$, the equality $\lambda= \alpha+\beta$ stands.

One can write $E_\delta$ as $\bigcup\limits_{\gamma\in E'} F_\gamma$ where $F_\gamma=\{(\alpha, \beta,\gamma) \,/\, (\alpha,\beta)\in E'_\gamma\}$ and this union is disjointed since are the $E'_\gamma$. Then we have (cf. explanations below)
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\delta}a_\alpha b_\beta c_\gamma = \sum\limits_{(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\in E_\delta} a_\alpha b_\beta c_\gamma & = \sum\limits_{\gamma\in E'} \sum\limits_{(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\in F_\gamma} a_\alpha b_\beta c_\gamma \tag{1}\\
& = \sum\limits_{\gamma\in E'} \left(\sum\limits_{(\alpha,\beta)\in E'_\gamma} a_\alpha b_\beta \right)c_\gamma \tag{2}\\
  & = \sum\limits_{\gamma+\lambda = \delta} \left(\sum\limits_{\alpha+\beta=\lambda} a_\alpha b_\beta \right) c_\gamma. \tag{3}
  \end{align*}

(1) results from the fact that the union on $E'$ is disjointed. In (2), $\gamma$ being set, we isolate the inner sum which extends on all the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $E'_\gamma$, that makes the parenthesis appear. In (3), one uses the initial remark about the leading of the inner sum: inner and outer sums are linked by the sum $\alpha+\beta$ which is called $\lambda$ as in $E'$.

We established the equality between $(ab)c$ and $d$, and one would show in the same way the equality between $a(bc)$ and $d$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the definition that $R[X_i]_{i\in I}=\bigcup_{F}R[X_i]_{i\in F}$ where the union is taken over all finite subsets  $F \subset I$.

Let $f_1,f_2,f_3\in R[X_i]_{i\in I}$. Then there are finite subsets $F_1,F_2,F_3$ of $I$ such that each $f_i\in R[X_i]_{i\in F_i}$. But then if we set $F=F_1\cup F_2 \cup F_3$, then $F$ is a finite subset of $I$, and the product $(f_1f_2)f_3$ in the whole ring $R[X_i]_{i\in I}$ is simply defined to be the product of the polynomials in the polynomial ring $R[X_i]_{i\in F}$ in finitely many variables. I'm sure you already know that this product is associative.

Comment: No, I define R[Xi] directly, so I want the proof for "infinite" variables... $R[X_i]$ is $A^{(J)}$ where $J=\mathbb{N}^{(I)}$.

Comment: Yes, but you easily show it reduces to the case of finite number of indeterminates.  For any finite subset $J\subset I$, $\,R[X_i]_{i\in J}\,$ is a subring of $\,R[X_i]_{i\in I}$.

Comment: No ! I have not yet defined the case of finite number of indeterminates ! My first chapter of my book starts with $R[X_i]_{i\in I}$ where $I$ is infinite ;). In this case, the question remains. And I want an answer to this one, not a trick to bypass the difficulties...